# Not able to fetch value for Update Data from database using jQuery Ajax Bootstrap Model - json data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

[image: console]My main problem is that my modal is showing but alert is showing [object Object]. I have four tables like stud,country_master_academic, master_city and master_state.When i click on edit, modal appears but data fetched from database is not showing in it.

jQuery in home.php page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
             $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function(event){
               var stud_no = $(this).attr("id");
               $.ajax({  
                    url:"update.php",  
                    method:"POST",  
                    data:{stud_no:stud_no},  
                    dataType:"json",  
                    success:function(data){  
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#name').val(data.name);
                    $('#mob_no').val(data.mob_no);
                    $('#dob').val(data.dob);
                    $('#add').val(data.add);
                    $('#photo').val(data.photo);
                    $('#gender').val(data.gender);
                    $('#country').val(data.country);
                    $('#state').val(data.state);
                    $('#city').val(data.city);
                    $('#stud_no').val(data.stud_no);
                    $('#update_data_modal').modal('show');  


                    },  
                    });     
                });  
    });
```

Modal for update in home.php page

```
<div class="container">
<div class="modal fade" id="update_data_modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-heading" style="margin-top:30px;text-align:center">
                <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-right:20px;font-weight:bold;">x</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>Update Student</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <?php
                $img = "images/".trim($vrow["photo"]);
                echo '<img src='.$img.' class="image" style="margin-left:75%;margin-top:5%;width:120px;height:120px;border:2px solid #bbbbbb;border-radius:10px;">';
                ?>
                <br/>
                <input type="file" name="photo"  style="margin-left:70%;">
                <div class="form-group">
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="form" id="form" method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <label for="name" id="name"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><b> Student Name: </b></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" pattern="[a-zA-Z]{3,}" title="Name should only contain letters and atleast 3 letters" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="no"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></span><b> Mobile No: </b></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mob_no" id="mob_no" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="Mobile number should be of 10 digits" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">    
                    <label for="dob"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span><b> Birth Date: </b></label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob" id="dob" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span><b> Address: </b></label>
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="33" class="form-control" name="add" id="add" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="photo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span><b> Photo: </b></label>
                    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gen"><b> Gender: </b></label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="M" required="required">Male
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="F" required="required">Female
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="cntry"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span><b> Country: </b></label>
                <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <?php 
                    $country="SELECT * from country_master_academic";
                    $res= $conn->query($country);
                    if($res->num_rows>0){
                        while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){        
                        if($row["country_name"]==$vcountry or $vrow['country'] == $row["country_code"] )
                        {   
                                echo '<option value='.$row["country_code"].' selected>'.$row["country_name"].'</option>';
                        }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<option value='.$row["country_code"].'>'.$row["country_name"].'</option>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                </select>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="state"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span><b> State: </b></label>
                <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <?php 
                    $state="SELECT * from master_state";
                    $res= $conn->query($state);
                    if($res->num_rows>0){
                        while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){        
                        if($row["state_name"]==$vstate or $vrow['state'] == $row["state_code"] )
                        {   
                                echo '<option value='.$row["state_code"].' selected>'.$row["state_name"].'</option>';
                        }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<option value='.$row["state_code"].'>'.$row["state_name"].'</option>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="city"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span><b> City: </b></label>
                <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control">
                <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <?php 
                    $city="SELECT * from master_city";
                    $res= $conn->query($city);
                    if($res->num_rows>0){
                        while($row=$res->fetch_assoc()){        
                        if($row["city_name"]==$vcity or $vrow['city'] == $row["city_code"] )
                        {   
                                echo '<option value='.$row["city_code"].' selected>'.$row["city_name"].'</option>';
                        }
                            else
                            {
                                echo '<option value='.$row["city_code"].'>'.$row["city_name"].'</option>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="hidden" name="stud_no" id="stud_no" />  
                    <button type="submit" name="update" id="update" class="btn btn-info">Update</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

update.php page but still i am trying to fetch data, so only wrote code for selecting records from database.

My edit button which is kept in a loop

```
    echo '<td><button name="edit" style="font-weight:bold;" type="submit" id='.$row["stud_no"].' class="btn btn-warning edit_data" data-target="#update_data_modal" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</button></td>';
```

Comment: Are you getting data on ajax success? check by `alert(data);` on ajax success.

Comment: @Yogendrasinh no

Comment: `s.stud_no={$id} or s.stud_no='".$id."'` use this...but i suggest use prepared statements

Comment: @Yogendrasinh in alert its showing object object

Comment: It is showing you the right thing as `data` under `success` function is an object, you have to parse it before use

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Are you saying to do it  $('#name').val(data.name); like this? Can you explain it with example,  how to parse value?

Comment: @JaicyJoseph use console.log(data) instead of alert

Comment: @madforstrength ok, i did it using console.log(data) but its not fetching values

Comment: @JaicyJoseph yes, try this way

Comment: @MayankPandeyz but its not working

Comment: @JaicyJoseph have you checked in your browser console? console.log will display value in browser console there you can see the response format and then modify your code accordinglly or paste it in your question

Comment: @madforstrength Its showing this Loading failed for the <script>

Comment: @JaicyJoseph is it hosted somewhere so that we can take a look?

Comment: @madforstrength How to get value of image? I have did it like this ->$('#photo').val(data.photo);

Comment: In object it is showing data, but not able to show it in textbox for updating @madforstrength

Comment: Is this code available on live site ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz no sir

Comment: In that case try to create a fiddle of your code and share the link of that

Comment: @MayankPandeyz Cannot make fiddle bcs of database, and i dont know to make fiddle, i tried but wr to put database details nd all

Comment: @JaicyJoseph Can you show your console.log data by taking screenshot of it? or just paste in your question that response so we can take a look at your response.

Comment: @Yogendrasinh Did it sir

Comment: @JaicyJoseph it seems your obejct has numeric indexes, you need to use `data[5]` instead of `data.photo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the snapshot, your object has numeric indexes hence `data.photo` will not return anything as there is no index `photo` in your object.

You can access image name by using `data[5]`.

Similarly you can get any index value.

Like for name instead of using `data.name` you need to use `data[1]`

So your code would be something like this:

```
$('#name').val(data[1]);
$('#mob_no').val(data[2]);
$('#dob').val(data[3]);
$('#add').val(data[4]);
$('#photo').val(data[5]);
```

Also you have given same ids for labels and inputs:

```
<label for="name" id="name">
```

You need to remove id from all labels:

```
<label for="name">
```

Comment: Did u mean it this way sir?
      $('#name').val(data[1]);
      $('#mob_no').val(data[2]);
      $('#dob').val(data[3]);
      $('#add').val(data[4]);

Comment: can you add `console.log(data[1]);` and show its output?

Comment: sir, its showing the value 'sjkfdha' , but how to take the value in textbox?

Comment: Oh the problem is you have given id to the label as well `<label for="name" id="name">` you need to remove id from all labels

Comment: that i removed before itself @madforstrength

Comment: Now only gender not able to fetch and i want to display the image which is stored in database... that i dont know to fetch... so have to try that. And thank u all for your help. i really appreciate you all.

Answer (score 2):

Change in your html as below.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="gen"><b> Gender: </b></label>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderMale" value="M" required="required">Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="genderFemale" value="F" required="required">Female
</div>
```

Add this code in your ajax success.

```
if(data[6] == 'M')
{
    $("#genderMale").prop("checked", true);
} else if(data[6] == 'F') {
    $("#genderFemale").prop("checked", true);
}
```

For image file you can use as below in your html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <img id="resultedPhoto">
    <label for="photo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></span><b> Photo: </b></label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" required />
</div>
```

Add below code in ajax success

```
$("#resultedPhoto").attr("src","/path-to-your-folder/" + data[5]);
```

Comment: not able to fetch city for 2 records. when i checked in console it is showing '12/t' ... only for those 2 records not showing city, while other all records city is showing @Yogendrasinh

Comment: do you have city data for those 2 records in your database?

Comment: yes. now i removed both those data, then inserted new records.

Comment: @JaicyJoseph if you want to update your data by ajax then write another ajax in your script else you can simply post your data to another page by submit form and refresh your page.

Comment: ya i tried that but didn't worked for me. Bcs how i will get stud_no in that? I cant get that. I dont know Ajax much, so cant get

Comment: You have to add one hidden input in your model <form> tag so you will get stud_no.

Comment: I did like that, but my modal is now not opening @Yogendrasinh

Comment: Can you show your updated code by changing it in your question?

Comment: Yes, i posted it, pls see above

Answer (score 0):

Now when i click on edit Modal is not opening and database value is getting empty
another jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form1").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
              $.ajax({
                 url:"upresult.php",
                 type:"POST",
                 data:{formData:formData},
                 async:false,
                 success:function(data) {
                   alert(data);
                    location.reload();
                },
                cache:false,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false
            });
         });

    });
```

upresult.php

```
    <?php
    include("connection.php");
    if(!empty($_POST)){
    $no=$_POST['stud_no'];
    $name=trim($_POST['name']);
    $mob=trim($_POST['mob_no']);
    $dob=trim($_POST['dob']);
    $add=trim($_POST['add']);
    $photo=trim($_FILES['photo']['name']);
    $gen=trim($_POST['gender']);
    $cn=trim($_POST['country']);
    $st=trim($_POST['state']);
    $ct=trim($_POST['city']);

    $qry="update stud set stud_name='$name',mobile='$mob',dob='$dob',address='$add',gender='$gen',country='$cn',state='$st',city='$ct' where stud_no='$no'";
    $data=mysqli_query($conn,$qry);
    if($data)
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Updated Successfully")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Cannot update record")';
        echo '</script>';
    }
    if(!empty($_FILES['photo']['name'])){
    $qry1= "update stud set photo='$photo' where stud_no='$no'";
    $data1=mysqli_query($conn,$qry1);

    if($data1){
        $target_dir="images/";
            $target_file=$target_dir.basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);
            $imageFileType=pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],$target_file)){
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("Image upload successfully")';
                echo '</script>';

            }  else {
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
                echo 'alert("Cannot Upload")';
                echo '</script>';
            }
    }
}

}
```